# Time period of periodic motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find time of one period in polar coordinates $( r, \theta) $

$ \dfrac {d \theta }  {dt} = \dfrac{ \sin \psi } {r}  $, $ \dfrac{dr}{dt} = \cos \psi ;$

obeying differential equation in a 2D plane

$ \dfrac{d\psi } {dt } = \sin \psi \,( \sin^{2} \psi/p -1/r) $

where p is a constant.

EDIT1: Apologies. Since there are three unknowns, one more necessary equation added.

Comment: OK, so what is the third equation?

Comment: added $ dr/dt = cos \psi $ in first line